# Prove that a number composed of only $2n$ "1"s, minus another number composed of only $n$ "2"s, is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

> Prove that a number composed of only $2n$ "1"s, minus another number composed of only $n$ "2"s, is a perfect square.

Examples:

$$11-2 = 9 = 3^2$$

$$1111 - 22 = 1089 = 33^2$$

**My try**

I saw that I can rearrange some of the "equations" like this

Examples:
$$1111-22 = 101(11)-(11)2=11(101-2)=11\cdot99 = 11^2 \cdot 9 = 11^2 \cdot3^2 = (11\cdot 3)^2$$

$$111111-222 = 1001(111)-(111)2 = 111(1001-2) = 111 \cdot 999 = 111^2 \cdot9 = (111\cdot 3)^2$$

I think this is enough to prove that statement but I want a more "elegant" or general way (maybe an algebraic way?), and also to know if my solution is correct.

Comment: I opened this thread hoping to see a proof that was perfectly square :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The number composed of $n$ ones is $(10^n-1)/9$. So your number is
$$\frac{10^{2n}-1}9-2\frac{10^n-1}9=\frac{a^2-1-2(a-1)}9$$
with $a=10^n$. I'll leave you to carry on...

Comment: It's not a2 - 1, it is a2 + 1 in the numerator. It wouldn't work otherwise...

Comment: @Maxim: are you sure? as it stands the -1 and the +2 (-2*-1) give an overall +1 in the numerator...

Comment: $a = 10^n$.   So we have in the numerator $(a^2 - 1)-2(a -1) = a^2 - 1 -2a + 2= a^2 - 2a + 1$ which seems perfectly correct to me.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen the (a - 1)... Shame on me

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$x=\underbrace{1\dots1}_n$$
For any $n$, the number in question is
$$\underbrace{1\dots1}_n\underbrace{0\dots0}_n-\underbrace{1\dots1}_n=x(10^n-1)=x(9x)=(3x)^2$$

Comment: It is subtracted by n twos, not n ones :-)

Comment: @Parcly Taxel , thanks for teaching me MathJax texting

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is two representative examples with the hope that by the two examples it should be clear without further rigor that it holds for all.

Which, of course, is not a proof.

Actually your only problem is lack of acceptable notation:

$\underbrace{111...}_{2n} - \underbrace{2222...}_2=$

$(1\underbrace{000...}_{n-1}1)*\underbrace{111...}_{n}-2*\underbrace{111...}_{n}=$

$(1\underbrace{000...}_{n-1}1-2)*\underbrace{111...}_{n}=$

$\underbrace{999999...9}_n*\underbrace{111...}_{n}=$

$9*\underbrace{111...}_{n}*\underbrace{111...}_{n}=9*\underbrace{111...}_{n}^2 = (3\underbrace{111...}_{n})$.

But we can formalize these generalizations:

1) $\underbrace{111...1}_{2n} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n-1} 10^i = 10^n*\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i$

$= (10^n + 1)\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i = 1\underbrace{000...0}_{n-1}1*\underbrace{11....1}_n$

2) $\underbrace{222....2}_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 2*10^i=2\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i = 2*\underbrace{11....1}_n$

3) $\underbrace{999....9}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 9*10^i=9\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i = 9*\underbrace{11....1}_n$

and $\underbrace{999....9}+1 = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 9*10^i + 1$ which equals $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} 9*10^i + (9*10^0 + 1) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} 9*10^i + 10^1 = \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} 9*10^i+(9*10^1 + 10^1) = ....$  via induction if we can show

$\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n-1} 9*10^i + 10^k = \sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{n-1} 9*10^i + (9*10^k + 10^k) =  \sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{n-1} 9*10^i + 10*10^k = \sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{n-1} 9*10^i + 10^{k+1}$.

So $\underbrace{999....9}+1 = \sum\limits_{i=n-1}^{n-1}9*10^i + 10^{n-1} = 9*10^{n-1} + 10^{n-1} = 10^n$

so $10^n -1 = \underbrace{999....9}$

[*And THAT was overkill.  You can state $10^n -1 = \underbrace{9999...9}_n$ without proof.  But... well, if we are getting fussy that giving two examples isn't a "proof" we can get fussy that ... "how do we KNOW $10^n -1 = \underbrace{9999...9}_n$"  ... well, THAT is how.*]

With that we can do your proof:

$\underbrace{111...1}_{2n}- \underbrace{222....2}_n=$

$(10^n + 1)\underbrace{111...1}_{n}- 2*\underbrace{111...1}_{n}=$

$(10^n+1 - 2)*\underbrace{111...1}_{n}=$

$(10^n - 1) *\underbrace{111...1}_{n}=$

$(9*\underbrace{111...1}_{n})*(\underbrace{111...1}_{n})$

$3^2* \underbrace{111...1}_{n}^2 = (3*\underbrace{111...1}_{n})^2$

=====

But if we are doing formal proofs.

It would behoove us for a few moments to prove that for any $a \ne 1$:

$1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + ...... + a^k = \frac {a^k - 1}{a-1}$

Pf:  $(a-1)(1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + ...... + a^k) =(a + a^2 + a^3 + ...... + a^{k+1}) -(1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + ...... + a^k)= a^{k+1} - 1$.

Which means $\underbrace{111...1}_n = 1 + 10 + 100 + ..... + 10^{n-1} = \frac {10^n -1}{10-1} = \frac {10^n-1}9$.

With that, Lord Sark's answer makes it easier:

$\underbrace{111...}_{2n} - \underbrace{222....2}_n =$

$\frac {10^{2n} - 1}{10 - 1} - 2\frac{10^{n} -1}{10-1} =$

$\frac {(10^n)^2 - 2*10^{n} + 1}{9} =(\frac {10^n - 1}{3})^2=$

$(\frac {(10-1)(1 + 10 + 100 + ..... )}3)^2= (3*\underbrace{111...11}_n)^2$.